# Confused about appending to a List

Tags: scala

I create a List like this :

```
var multiList : List[MyObj] = Nil
```

To append objects to this List I use :

```
multiList = multiList ::: List(MyObj)
```

this works but should I not be using

```
multiList = multiList ::: MyObj
```

as here I am appending an object to the List, wheras in example (that works) it looks syntactically as if im appending a new List to a List ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:::` operators mean concatenate, not append. There's `:+` for element-append.

Comment: I want to stress that `:+` as an O(n) complexity in the case of lists (it is necessary to peruse the whole list to append to it) so you should switch to another data structure if you need to append often. See [Scala Collections Performance Characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `::` method is used to 'prepend' stuff to a list. The `:::` operator is used to prepend one list to another. The `::` ends with a colon and thus is 'right associative' which can be explained as follows

x :: y

// will be translated to

y.::(x)

So to add your object to an empty list you could do

MyObj :: Nil

// will be translated to

Nil.::(MyObj)

If you wanted to add a list of objects to an empty list you could do

List(MyObj, MyObj) ::: Nil

// will be translated to

Nil.:::(List(MyObj, MyObj))

If you do want to append you could use the `:+` method. This however performs differently for different types of collections. More info about the perfomance can be found here: [Performance Characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html)